# Redux-saga: Best way to handle async call data used in only one component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I need advice concerning redux-saga and the way to handle async call. I don't find anwsers to my questions.

I would like to know **how can I handle properly async API call which return data used in only one component (so useless to store it in the store) ?**

In my react application, I use redux-saga to handle async call. When the saga finish correctly, I dispatch a success action which store result in the store.

However, i find useless to store the result when I only want to display it in one component. Instead I would like to run a saga and return by a callback data to my component without storing it int the store. Is it possible ? How can I do that ?

thanks.

Comment: Why do you use redux-saga for such an api call, just use fetch in `componentDidMount` of that component and save the needed data to the state after ?

Comment: Yes, I totally aggree with this way tot do it. I wanted to know if it was a good pratice to use local state and redux. Therefore in which reason is used redux-saga ?? Maybe when you want to proceed a async call and continue to navigaute into you application ?? what other usecase ?

Comment: @onedkr - there are many reason to use local state, there is no strict rule that forces you to use only redux store. In your case it makes sense to store the data in your local state, since it doesn't effect other components in your app. So you don't need to use. In regards to redux-saga, Have you tried to return `yield response.json();` in your saga? that should work from `componentDidMount()`

Comment: @jank I never try to return response.json() but how can I retrieve it from the saga or from my dispatch({ type:MY_ACTION }) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for you, that code makes an api request in `componentDidMount` lifecycle and sets the data to its state and after it renders it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

      console.log('response.data: ', response.data);

      this.setState({
        data: response.data
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error: ', error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(item => <li>{item.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apparently it not recommanded to use setState in componentDidMount. It trigger re-rendering which can causes performance issues.

Comment: You have to rerender after you get your data anyway. Its not a wasted rerender here.

Comment: @onedkr actually I recommend you to read react's documentatin

`You should populate data with AJAX calls in the componentDidMount lifecycle method. This is so you can use setState to update your component when the data is retrieved.
` 

it says.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html